# JQuery Scroll Speeds and Animations

Tags: jquery, animation

http://www.melanie-f.com/en/

I found this site via siteInspire today, and I really liked the look of it. I had a couple questions:

1- The scrolling effect -- I'm hesitant to call it parallax, as I have trouble distinguishing what is or is not parallax nowadays -- I like how it's used here, but is this generally considered annoying to users? Are there any tutorials for this that you'd recommend?

2- How are the animated letters that accompany each shoe displayed? I see they are image sprites, but what script allows them to "play" in quick succession when a user scrolls to them?

Thanks!